# simple shell using execlp goes weirdly

Tags: c, unix, process, exec, fork

I am reading **GNU/Linux application programming the 2nd edition**,you can reach what am reading from [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=KjEq9Mua5TQC&pg=PA197&lpg=PA197&dq=simpshell.c&source=bl&ots=1TaleVDIpV&sig=u5GVnd1xU4t3SCM7qtp6O1K620c&hl=en&ei=HKheTM-lDYqQuAPPrdiZDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=simpshell.c&f=false).After I write the code similar to his,but it work strangely:

```
$ ./shell
./shell>>quit
$ ./shell
./shell>>date
Sun Aug  8 21:19:37 CST 2010
./shell>>quit
$ ./shell
./shell>>abc
execlp failed: No such file or directory
./shell>>quit
./shell>>quit
$./shell 
./shell>>abcd execlp
execlp failed: No such file or directory
./shell>>quit 
./shell>>quit
```

The first and second cases are ok,but the third and forth ones somewhat need two **quit** to quit.This is not what i am expecting.I guess something is wrong with **fork()**,or the **waitpid()**,but this still got unsolved after asking a few people around me.Now is summer time, i.e. summer holiday,I got no more mates to go for.Thanks always.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_LEN 80

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

 pid_t pid;
 char cmd[LINE_LEN+1]={'\0'};

 while(1)
 {
  printf("%s>>",argv[0]);
  if(fgets(cmd,sizeof(cmd),stdin)==NULL)
  {
   perror("fgets failed");
   break;
  }
  cmd[strlen(cmd)-1]='\0';
  if(strncmp(cmd,"quit",4)==0)
  {
   break;
  }
  if((pid=fork())==-1)
  {
   perror("fork failed");
   break;
  }else if(pid==0)
  {
   //TODO no option can be specified for cmd
   execlp(cmd,cmd,NULL);
   perror("execlp failed");
  }else
  {
   waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
  }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, if `execlp` succeeds, your child process becomes the new process, and thus execution of your code effectively stops at that point.

Now the `execlp` failed, you print out the error, and *continue the child process as if nothing happened!* You should `exit(0)` the child, if the `execlp` failed.

Comment: Thanks.I see what you mean.The code in the book does not do any error check about execlp,So this fix may go to the errata?

Comment: definitely! If your book doesn't say so, remember this: *always check return values*

Comment: (although, for the `exec` class of functions, the fact that your code is still alive is an indication of failure, so checking a return value is strictly not needed to know things went wrong...)

Comment: Thanks again.You answered this question so quick.I love stackoverflow.com.So professional,but I am just a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

`execlp` will fail if `cmd` does not exist.

As [mvds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371793/mvds) rightly said, when `execlp` fails, you should exit the child process. But I recommend not forking when `cmd` does not exist.

You could use something like `access` (see [access(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access)) before using `fork` to make sure `cmd` exists (within your `PATH`), and is an executable.

Comment: Yes,I should call access before pass cmd to execlp.Thanks a lot.

Comment: UPDATE:access(with X_OK) only check pathname,not filename(i.e. I have to figure out it with path.)

Answer (score 0):

Just post the debug version to make it clear:strncmp is called in which process,and when child or parent exit

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_LEN 80

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

    pid_t pid;
    char cmd[LINE_LEN+1]={'\0'};

    while(1)
    {
        printf("%s>>",argv[0]);
        if(fgets(cmd,sizeof(cmd),stdin)==NULL)
        {
            perror("fgets failed");
            break;
        }
        cmd[strlen(cmd)-1]='\0';
        if(strncmp(cmd,"quit",4)==0)
        {
            printf("process :%d in strncmp equal\n",getpid());
            break;
        }
        if((pid=fork())==-1)
        {
            perror("fork failed");
            break;
        }else if(pid==0)
        {
            printf("new child:%d\n",getpid());
            //TODO no option can be specified for cmd
            execlp(cmd,cmd,NULL);
            perror("execlp failed");
            //This is critical
            //exit(0);
        }else
        {
            printf("parent:%d(his child is %d)\n",getpid(),pid);
            waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
        }
    }
    printf("process :%d exit...\n",getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

just see one case:

```
./shell
./shell>>abc
parent:8356(his child is 8357)
new child:8357
execlp failed: No such file or directory
./shell>>quit
process :8357 in strncmp equal
process :8357 exit...
./shell>>quit
process :8356 in strncmp equal
process :8356 exit...
```